# Look for a file in a theme before loading from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, filesystem

I am developing a plugin and I would like users to be able to override specific files from their theme.

For example: I am including the file `people.php`, located in:

`/plugins/my_plugin/view/people.php`

Anyone can add a file to their theme / child theme as well, by putting it in this location:

`/themes/my_theme/my_plugin/view/people.php`

I know that Woocommerce supports this functionality.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce use [locate_template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) for checking if file exists in theme or not

Comment: Cool - this helps. I had to write a bit of code to get this to work as I needed, but thank you!

Comment: welcome @JacobRaccuia